# What Happens In Linux During Context Switching

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, process-management

During process execution in Linux, which action causes the context switching after process time slice?

Is it uses of timer interrupt causing or making the CPU Scheduler Context switching or is it using something else ?